# Is there any way to extract text from a Flash-based website?

Tags: flash, string

I'd like to code a scrobbling utility for Grooveshark using Last.FM's API but I don't know if it's possible to get the song information from the Grooveshark's Flash frontend. Is there any way to get strings from a .swf?

I'd post some more information but I'm not able to post links yet since I'm a new user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Odds are the song information is not embedded in the SWF but passed over HTTP calls, encoded either in XML or AMF.  You can use a web debugging proxy to examine the information that goes over the wire.  Charles is a great tool that supports both XML and AMF encodings.

http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there's any possibility doing so. Flash files are independant embeeded objects which contain everything within itself. You might try search for a Flash File Decoder to fetch out data from the Flash compiled files, but I dont suggest this practice.

Thanks.